# Smartclient have any deferred and promise

Tags: smartclient

I have sendRequest using RPCManager in smartclient. but I have to structure chaining execution. I read on internet about jQuery deferred and promise function. But I wonder whether smartclient support execution in sequential task.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

queueing may be what are you looking for?

For example:

```
RPCManager.startQueue();
grid.updateData(record1, function(dsResponse, data, dsRequest){/*callback1*/});
grid.updateData(record2, function(dsResponse, data, dsRequest){/*callback2*/});
RPCManager.sendQueue(function(responses){/*finalCallback*/});
```

will execute the updates sequentially, in a single request, and the callbacks will be executed sequentially:

1. callback1
2. callback2
3. finalCallback